# how to get url insetead of status of login in python

Tags: python-3.x

the automation i am trying to do has multilevel authorisation and usage of token.  while doing it
manually, a sucessful login takes me to a page where there is token in the url.  however, when i 
automate the login, it gives only a status of 200 which is a success but does not give the url, which
is required for getting the token. I have the tried the following

input:
url='https://kite.trade/connect/login?api_key=850dzgza7n8j8ca8&v=3'
r=requests.get(url,data=values)

output:
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): kite.trade:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://kite.trade:443 "GET /connect/login?api_key=850dzgza7n8j8ca8&v=3 HTTP/1.1" 302 None
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): kite.zerodha.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://kite.zerodha.com:443 "GET /connect/login?api_key=850dzgza7n8j8ca8&v=3 HTTP/1.1" 302 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://kite.zerodha.com:443 "GET /connect/login?api_key=850dzgza7n8j8ca8&sess_id=vdXa2vw2axunB74yAmscJRcInLEORqgL HTTP/1.1" 200 None

can some one guide how to get the subsequent url instead of just the status.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
url = 'https://kite.trade/connect/login?api_key=850dzgza7n8j8ca8&v=3'
r = requests.get(url)
print (r.url)

> https://kite.zerodha.com/connect/login?api_key=850dzgza7n8j8ca8&sess_id=[sess_id]
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: hi.. no. I want to extract the subsequent url

Comment: Can you give an example output of what you want

Comment: if i input the password and pin it takes to this url. i want this url to be captured in the program. https://kite.trade/?action=login&status=success&request_token=I7n7jKrPoOgYfkUERyndZMik2ChxMxXU.